# Can I use attribute name to call the setter?

Tags: php

For example, I have the class attribute name which stored in a varible.

```
$name='id';
```

And then I want do this without write the function name in code.

```
$someObject->setId(123);
```

How to use PHP to do that?

Comment: He/she wants to set/get C# style without implementing the code to do so.

Comment: @Flash Thunder -- why comment then?

Comment: @CL So you'll have to settle for $someObject->setName(123); or it will be a bit more work to map each one out in a switch statement for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is possible, though your camelwriting is something to pay attention to.

```
$name = 'id'; // id
$name = ucfirst($name); // Id
$name = 'set' . $name; // setId
$someObject->$name(123); // $someObject->setId(123);
```

Comment: That is the exactly what I want

Answer (score 2):

just implement a `__set` method:

```
public class a{
   private $id;

   public function __set($name, $val){
      $this->$name = $val; //note the "$" before name.
   }
}
```

usage:

```
$b = new a();
$b->id = 5;
```

(will be internally translated to: `__set("id", 5)`

but tbh: If you implement all `setter` in a generic style - why not simple make the property `$id` `public` instead?

Comment: __set()/__get() are called Magic Methods in PHP.. __autoload() being the most powerful, imho ;)

Comment: set wont work for $this->setFoo(8);  Op doesn't want dynamic properties just a dynamic getter and setter.

Comment: `but tbh: If you implement all setter in a generic style - why not simple make the property $id public instead?`, yes, you are right, so I think that magic method is not suitable. Because each properties in the class have different rule, so I cannot simply use same method to set/get all properties.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [PHP Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php), they have a lot of powerful automagical methods that you can implement in your Classes.

Comment: This is more commentary rather than an answer

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
public function __call($method, $args){
    $method = strtolower($method);
    $_method = substr($method, 3);
    $_prop = substr($method, 0, 3);

    if(!property_exists($this, $_method)){
        throw new Exception('Call to undefined method '.__CLASS__.'::'.$method.'()');
    }

    if($_method == 'set'){
        if(empty($args)){
            $this->{$_prop} = null;
        }else{
            $this->{$_prop} = $args[0];
        }
    }else if($_method == 'get'){
        return $this->{$_prop};
    }
}
```

That said __call and the other magic methods, are a lot slower then just writing your own method.  Also this assumes that your class properties will be all lowercase like this

```
$this->setFoo > protected $foo;
$this->setFooToo > protected $footoo;
$this->setFoo_Too > protected $foo_too;
```

If you want them not like this, change this part

```
$method = strtolower($method);
$_method = substr($method, 3);
$_prop = substr($method, 0, 3);
```

To

```
//$method = strtolower($method); -- remove this line
$_method = substr($method, 3);
$_prop = lcfirst( substr($method, 0, 3) );
```

And then you have

```
$this->setFoo > protected $foo;
$this->setFooToo > protected $fooToo;
$this->setFoo_Too > protected $foo_Too;
```

It will throw a similar error that it would if you try accessing an unknown property.

Comment: If use magic method, I still need to write the method name explicitly, so it is not suitable